# Does Git have any labels?

Tags: git, label, development-environment

I have a situation where I have multiple work environments involved in a pipeline and at any given moment they could be working on a certain version of a file. What I was wondering is if there is a per file label that you could have that would be used to maintain which environment has a certain version (or any other attribute).
[NOTE: This would all be done on command line]

I looked into tags but they seemed like more of a tool to define these versions. I really need a per file option

Basically I need to add multiple labels like "Dev v1.02" AND "Test v1.01" per file.

Think of these labels as attributes.

Comment: Why not just use commit hashes?

Comment: Every committed file has a hash ID that identifies that particular *content* (without a name): try, e.g., `git rev-parse master:path/to/file` to see the current hash ID of the contents that, if you `git checkout master`, will be copied out under the name `path/to/file`. (The *name* is stored as part of the commit, not as part of the file.) You cannot assign these hash IDs as they're just a cryptographic checksum of the internal object contents, but that might be what you need.

Comment: Could you describe more your situation with work environments? Are these developments of a given file in parallel or just versions it goes through before production?

Comment: I need to add a label like "Dev v1.02" AND "Test v1.01" per file. I cannot stress enough that it is at the FILE level which is why I do not think tags would work.